# Using 'needs' from an Ember Object

Tags: ember.js

I use needs on some controllers to access the `currentRouteName` in the default application controller. All it takes is:

```
needs: ['application'],
routeBinding: 'controllers.application.currentRouteName',
```

Works a charm. Now I'm trying to do precisely the same thing from an Ember.Object instead of a Ember.Controller and it's not liking it. How do I solve this? I was guessing that the scope for 'needs' might need to be something like:

```
needs: ['controllers.application']
```

but that didn't solve it. Anyone else crack this nut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

needs only works inside of controllers.

accessing a controller from a model would be considered an anti-pattern.  What you want to do is move up the logic out of the model, and into whatever controllers are decorating the model (if it's many controllers you'll want to create a mixin and add that mixin to the appropriate controllers).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eFILEBUq/5/edit

Comment: Ok a mixin might be a good approach. I had hoped to provide a "routeManager" object that would provide some utility ways to understand the current route and have that object injected into each of the controllers so they could access the current route with `this.routeManager.currentRoute`, get all the segments individually with `this.routeManager.routeSegments`, etc.

Comment: A route manager controller would work really well, it could be a singleton instance that was setup during the application controller and all of your other controllers could access it easily using needs etc.

Comment: I did try this but ran into a problem with the `needs: ['application']` call which created a `Assertion failed: Error while loading route: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. No idea and I ran away exasperated.

Comment: Seems like such a basic pattern ... I wish there were some better examples out there (or something built into core). Ahh well. If you know of anything I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: that sounds like a recursion issue, were you grabbing a property that depended on itself?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so ... the controller literally had a single line in it: `needs: ['application']`

Comment: Check out the example above, and feel free to modify

Comment: Yeah, adding a needs to your own controller will cause a stack overflow

Comment: Cool, that's exactly what I was thinking. Tired of trying to "inject to success" I'd prefer to take your mixin route. Thanks for sticking with me.